# Propagation of a flat-top laser beam in free space

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, laser, simulations, photonics

I have spent some time looking at how to design a field mapping system that turns a Gaussian beam profile into a top-hat beam. However, it would also be very useful to have a very sharp super-Gaussian profile for a different experiment.

I have found a page (the [RP Photonics article on flat-top beams](https://www.rp-photonics.com/flat_top_beams.html)) which argues that since the top-hat is not a free space mode of the Helmholtz equation, the profile changes as it propagates. From the simulated model (*Figure 1*) and the description given by the author it looks to me like the top-hat might initially collapse to something resembling a super-Gaussian but its a bit hand-wavy to deduce that from an intensity plot.

[image: Simulation of varying intensity profile of a top-hat beam with longitudinal propagation (*Paschotta, R*)]

My question now is: Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to replicate this simulation or at least find a way to solve for the specific intensity profile I am looking for. 
Which equations do I use and how can I apply them for a computational solution (I'm guessing the solutions will have to be numerically evaluated)?

Or alternatively, is my reasoning just plain wrong and the profile does not contract into a super Gaussian as the beam propagates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial flat-top function is often assumed to be a super-Gaussian function
$$ \exp\left(-\frac{r^n}{w^n}\right) . $$
Unfortunately, super-Gaussians are a bit unfriendly to use in analytic calculations. So it is probably better to due it numerically. The simplies why to do this is to use, what is called beam-propagation:

- Take the 2D Fourier transform of the function (numerically: 2D FFT)
- Multiply with the propagation kernel:
  $ \exp\left(i\pi\lambda z r^2\right) $ where $r$ is the radial coordinate in the Fourier domain, $z$ is the propagation distance and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.
- Do the inverse Fourier transform to get the field at the new $z$-location.

There are a few subtleties with such numerical implementations, but I trust you'll figure them out.

Comment: Don’t you mean convolve with $\exp (i\pi {{r}^{2}}/\lambda z)$ in the spatial domain or multiply the Fourier Xform by $\exp (-iz{{k}^{2}}\lambda /4\pi )$?

Comment: @BertBarrois: the problem is notation. That is why I said $r$ is the radial coordinate in the *Fourier domain*. So in terms of your notation $|k|=2\pi r$. Usually $k$ is the wave number $k=2\pi/\lambda$. The difference in sign in the exponent is determined by the phase convention.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any beam profile can be expressed as a sum of plane-waves, it can also be decomposed in Hermite functions.

To do so, consider a beam propagating in the z-direction. The electric field can be expressed as the product of an envelop $u$ and a carrier $e^{ikz}$ :
$$
E_{m,n}(x,y,z) = A\times u_{m,n}(x,y,z) \exp\left( ikz \right) 
$$
and the propagation of the envelop can be expressed as
$$
u_{m,n}(x,y,z)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{w(z)}} \phi_n(\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{w(z)}) \phi_m(\frac{y\sqrt{2}}{w(z)}) \exp\left(ik\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2R(z)} \right)\exp(-i \psi_{m,n}(z)) \quad (1)
$$
where
$$
\psi_{m,n}(z) = (n+m+1) \arctan\frac{z}{z_R} \\
w(z)=w_0 \sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{z_R ^2}} \\
R(z) = z + \frac{z_R ^2}{z} \\
z_R = \frac{\pi w_0 ^2}{\lambda}
$$
and $\phi_n$ is the Hermite function defined as 
$$
\phi_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}e^{-x^2}
$$

Typically, for $n=m=0$, you recover the standard Gaussian propagation.

All this come from Maxwell equation. Now, there is a theorem that any function $v(x,y)$ can be expressed as a sum of functions $u_{n,m}$ :
$$
v(x,y)=\sum_{n,m} \, C_{n,m} u_{n,m}(x,y,0)
$$
with
$$
C_{n,m} = \int u^*_{n,m}(x,y,0)\times v(x,y) \,dxdy
$$

So you should take v(x,y) as a top hat and calculate $C_{n,m}$ - this will tell you how gaussian beams superpose to give a top hat at $z=0$. Then, the propagation equation (1) will tell you how this superposition looks like away from $z=0$.